# different instance in different environment provision using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Suppose I have two environment Production and Staging and Now I want to provision t2.large in Staging and m5.large in Production. How to write a terraform script without using any conditional format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use workspaces:
create your resources, for example:

```
# Define provider AWS
provider "aws" {
  region = "your_aws_region"
}

# Create an EC2 instance
resource "aws_instance" "staging_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   # Enter your desired AMI ID
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  subnet_id     = "your_subnet_id"       # Enter your subnet ID
  key_name      = "your_key_pair_name"   # Enter your key pair name
  tags = {
    Name = "staging_instance"
    Environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

initialize Terroform:

```
terraform init
```

create a workspace:

```
terraform workspace new staging
```

plan and apply as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled by using the terraform workspace feature. The code would look similar to what Mohammed Ehab posted, but with some slight changes:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  .
  .
  .
  instance_type = terraform.workspace == "staging" ? "t2.large" : "m5.large"
  .
  . 
  .

  tags = {
    Name        = "${terraform.workspace}_instance"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

You could also create local variables that would help you control what gets deployed:

```
locals {
  instance_type = terraform.workspace == "staging" ? "t2.large" : "m5.large"
  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
    Name        = "${terraform.workspace}_instance"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  .
  .
  .
  instance_type = local.instance_type
  .
  . 
  .

  tags = local.tags
}
```

If you are going to use workspaces, make sure to switch between them when applying to the environment you want:

```bash
terraform workspace select <name of the workspace>
```

You would of course have to create the workspace first:

```
terraform workspace new <name of the workspace>
```

Alternatively, as workspaces come with their set of limitations, you could just create two different directories, define a variable and use that, e.g. for staging:

```
variable "env" {
  type        = string
  description = "Environment to deploy the code into."
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "EC2 instance type to deploy."
}
```

And then have a `terraform.tfvars` file in each of the directories with the following values:

```
# staging directory
env           = "staging"
instance_type = "t2.large"
```

```
# production directory
env           = "production"
instance_type = "m5.large"
```

The code for the instance would look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  .
  .
  .
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  .
  . 
  .

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}_instance"
    Environment = var.env
  }
}
```